# Rendering through form submission in AJAX

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I wanted my advanced search form to retain it's form fields values after submission, so I changed the form with method=POST, to ajax. My controller is still working great, I am able to make my rest calls, and get the data as a result.

The problem is I don't know how to render the page again with ajax. I don't want ajax to have anything to do with the response as the response logic is built into advanced_search_order_table. I just need Ajax to reload advanced_search_orders_table.

```
<%= render "advanced_search_orders_form" %>
<div id="advanced_search_orders_table" class="fk-table ajax">
  <%= render "advanced_search_orders_table" %>
</div>
```

In advanced_search_orders_form.html.erb (Partial snippet only)

```
form id="advancedSearchOrder" name="advancedSearchForm" value="advancedSearch" class=" search line" action="" onsubmit="return submitForm();">

<div class="advancedSearchFormField">
      <span class="advancedSearchFormlabel">Order Id</span>
      <%= text_area_tag('filters[order_id]',filter_params['order_id'],:rows=>10) %>
</div>

<div class="advancedSearchFormSelectField">
  <span class="advancedSearchFormlabel"> Order Sales Channel </span>

  <%= select_tag 'filters[order_sales_channel]',
                  options_for_select(
                          [["Web", "Web"], ["Phone", "Phone"]]
                  ),
                  selected: filter_params['order_sales_channel'],
                  multiple: true,
                  class: "advancedSearchFormSelectBox" %>
</div>

<input type="submit" class="advanced-search-btn" id="advancedSearchButton" name="advancedSearchButton" value="Search"/>
```

And I have defined submitForm as

```
function submitForm() {
    $.ajax({type:'POST',url: '', data:$('#advancedSearchOrder').serialize(), success: function(response) {
        /*Render advanced_search_orders_table here */
    }});

    return false;
}
```

Comment: What does the `advanced_search_orders_form` look like? Is there a reason why you choose to not use `form_for`?

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan - Don't know how that helps, but I have used a lot of Rails feature too...Mix & Match.

Answer (score 0):

Simply parse your response using JavaScript. Basically remove the rows from the table and then for each result add a row. You could add some nice animations as well ;)

Another option would be to respond to that AJAX call with an already rendered HTML page that contains the data and you simply replace the table with the new one (using JavaScript again). I can`t tell which would perform better.